# Example named pipes IPC with read/write timeout

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm struggling with finding the best way to implement named pipes IPC with a robust timeout management. I don't mean timeout on establishing a connection but timeout on read/write streams.

All examples I find don't have a timeout implementation.

Can someone give me a working example and/or point me to an example that shows this?

Comment: Are you trying to use straight Named Pipes or are you looking at using WCF over Named Pipes?

Comment: @AdamGritt: straight named pipes.

Answer (score 3):

What you'll probably have to do is do asynchronous reading and writing with `NamedPipeClientStream.BeginRead` and `NamedPipeClientStream.BeginWrite`; a timer will then be used to detect when data hasn't been sent or received for a period of time.

Whenever data is sent or received, a `DateTime` field will be set to `DateTime.Now`, and each execution of the timer will check on that field to determine if a timeout occurs. If one occurs, the `NamedPipeClientStream` can be closed, and the exceptions from `NamedPipeClientStream.EndRead` and `NamedPipeClientStream.EndWrite` can be caught.

I don't have a working example ready yet, but I'll get to work on one if you need it. Hopefully this will help you out in the mean time.

---

This is some very rough example code. A lot more would need to be done, such as implement `IDisposable` and add write methods. This should help illustrate the idea, though. It would probably best to use this code as a model, rather than use it directly. I've tested the code to see if it reads.

```
//this is a very rough model of how to do it. a lot more would need to be implemented
//i'm assuming you plan to continuously read from it. i can think up another example if you're not
//also not thread safe
public class MyPipeClient
{
    NamedPipeClientStream PipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream("testpipe1");
    Timer TimeoutTimer;
    DateTime LastRead;
    const int TimeoutSeconds = 120; //2 mins

    //will connect and start receiving
    public void Connect()
    {
        PipeClient.Connect();
        LastRead = DateTime.Now;

        TimeoutTimer = new Timer(TimeoutCheck, this, 0, 1000); //check every second

        Read(this);
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        PipeClient.Close(); PipeClient = null;
        TimeoutTimer.Dispose(); TimeoutTimer = null;
    }

    static void Read(MyPipeClient client)
    {
        PipeState state = new PipeState(client);

        try
        {
            client.PipeClient.BeginRead(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, ReadCallback, state);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException) //disconnected/disposed
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        PipeState state = (PipeState)ar.AsyncState;
        MyPipeClient client = state.Client;

        client.LastRead = DateTime.Now;

        int bytesRead;

        try
        {
            bytesRead = client.PipeClient.EndRead(ar);
        }
        catch (IOException) //closed
        {
            return;
        }

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            byte[] data = state.Buffer;

            //TODO: something
        }
        else //i've never used pipes, so i'm assuming this behavior exists with them
        {
            client.Disconnect();
            return;
        }

        Read(client);
    }

    static void TimeoutCheck(object state)
    {
        MyPipeClient client = (MyPipeClient)state;

        TimeSpan timeSinceLastRead = DateTime.Now - client.LastRead;

        if (timeSinceLastRead.TotalSeconds > TimeoutSeconds)
        {
            client.Disconnect();
        }
    }
}

class PipeState
{
    public byte[] Buffer = new byte[4096];
    public MyPipeClient Client;

    public PipeState(MyPipeClient client)
    {
        Client = client;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great example; I'll try this.