# Block user from opening a form if other instance has this user

Tags: c#, winforms

My WinForm Application must open specific form according to logged users. At the Login Form, the user authentication is completed, where user gives username-password. The valid credentials are inside a .csv file. If the user is valid, Login Form is hidden and Form2 appears.

What I want to do is to block a user who opens the application (Login Form) and gives the same username-password with someone who already runs this app.
My current solution is to add to each process (instance) an environment variable with the login's username like this:

```
Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
proc.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Add("G2GUser",username);
```

And when another instance opens, checkes if the user who tries to log in is already uses the application. So, this variable is being checked:

```
List<Process> processes =     System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)).ToList();
foreach (Process proc in processes)
{
   StringDictionary sd = proc.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables;
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sd["G2GUser"]))
      if (sd["G2GUser"] == username) {; //block this user}
}
```

The problem is that I can see the processes' list, but EnvironmentVariables are not stored. Can you propose another way for this approach?

Comment: You want to block more user on the same machine or on different machine (LAN)? Or you want simply to block the reopening of the same app on the same computer?

Comment: if you want to prevent the use from opening up another `Instance` of the application, then you will need to create a `Mutex`

Comment: @DJKRAZE a mutex would be great for limiting multiple instances, but it appears he wants to limit some in-app behaviour if another instance is running with the same user logged in to the application; no doubt he wants this to limit shared access to some state or to prevent simultaneous modification.

Comment: Got Cha.. thanks for the clarification `Clint`

Comment: @Clint "limit some in-app behaviour if another instance is running with the same user logged in to the application ..."  That's exactly what I want. Communication between my instances and block in-app behavior according to login form

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using the environment variables.

Given you could have any arbitrary number of instances of the application you'll need to maintain some form of tracking these users.

You could communicate between the applications by making use of inter-process communication such as `Named pipes` see: [Example named pipes IPC with read/write timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536337/example-named-pipes-ipc-with-read-write-timeout)

Then by communicating back and forth between the instances you could make decisions between them.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but it seems very confusing for my problem. The only thing I want to check during user login is a variable from other instances. Why environment variables is not a solution?

Comment: @kk_nou environment variables are typically used for search paths and the like, you **could** use them, but they create problems, for example: What happens if a user logs out of an instance? Every other instance could then potentially have out of date information about the current user. I'll post some form of example with this answer to get you started.

Comment: @kk_nou do you need to know how many of the other instances have that user logged in, or just need to know that another instance has that particular user logged in?

Comment: @kk_nou if all you need to do is see if another instance has that user logged in, you get creative with the name of a `Mutex` new Mutex("MyApplication_user_usernamehere"), have it as initially owned and check the `createdNew` `out` parameter if it's true then you're the first instance, if it's false then another instance has a mutex of the same name.

Comment: I need to know that another instance has that particular user logged in. Also to question: "What happens if a user logs out of an instance?" Each user must close the program, he cannot logout. I will try the solution with the Mutex. Thanks a lot!